# How can i add coupon code box on onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, coupon-codes

I need customer can apply coupon code at the stage of checkout. How can i  add coupon code apply box on onepage checkout

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried?

Comment: solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25540687